# Removing certain things from being scraped

Tags: php

Currently I am scraping this website with the code displayed below but it displays sometimes pages with *Mixtape* in the title and I am wondering how I can make it skip over these and only crawl the pages that display normally. ([demo](http://movies.wubstub.com/t/dancehall.php))

```
$html = file_get_html('http://beatshype.com/mp3download/');
foreach($html->find('.entry-title a') as $element) 
{
    print '<br><br>';
    echo $url = ''.$element->href;

    $html2 = file_get_html($url);
    
    print '<br>';

    $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
    print $image = $image->content;
    
    print '<br>';
    
    $title = $html2->find('.single-title',0);
    print $title  = $title->plaintext;
    
    print '<br>';
    
    $str = explode ("/", $url);     
    
    $date = $html2->find('.single-content a',2);
    print $date = $date->href;
}
```

Screenshot: [image]

Top result is good, bottom result is bad.

Comment: check this out.. http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/11/01/a-highly-flexible-php-web-crawler-library/ ..youcan use the `IGNORE_LINKS_LIKE`  setting to ignore links with that string in the title

Comment: @Pamblam sorry I should have been more specific this is not going to help me at all, I am using [Simple HTML dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Comment: idk how that's relevant.. it could help you, but it would be much easier to use the answer below..

Comment: You may want also to use `$title = str_replace('â€“','&#8211',$title)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple, check if the title contains 'mixtape' and go to the next item in the loop:

```
if(stripos($title->plaintext, 'mixtape') !== false) {
    continue;
}
```

Put that code just before you assign `$title` to `$title->plaintext`, or just use $title as the haystack argument.

---

Some people need it spelled out..

```
$html = file_get_html('http://beatshype.com/mp3download/');
foreach($html->find('.entry-title a') as $element) 
{
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    $title = $html2->find('.single-title',0);
    if(stripos($title, 'mixtape') !== false) continue;
    $title  = $title->plaintext;

    print '<br><br>';
    echo $url = ''.$element->href;

    print '<br>';

    $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
    print $image = $image->content;

    print $title.'<br>';

    $str = explode ("/", $url);     

    $date = $html2->find('.single-content a',2);
    print $date = $date->href;
}
```

Comment: Can you at least point out any errors you are getting? Where are you putting my code?

Comment: Added this `if(stripos($title->plaintext, 'MIXTAPE:') !== false) {
   continue;
  }` right after `print $title  = $title->plaintext;` with no success

Comment: you need to do `strtoupper()` on both sides to make it casde insensitive

Comment: strtoupper isn't needed, stripos is the case insensitive version of strpos.
Regarding the position of my code, you are immediately overriding the $title with the plaintext property, making it a string. Move the code above the string assignment or change the first stripos argument to just `$title`

Comment: Yea, this isn't working at all and I'm not sure why because reading the documentation behind **stripos** it should be working. Could you edit your answer with the position of where I need to include this line of code?

Comment: _Move the code above the string assignment or change the first stripos argument to just $title_

Comment: It's working, it;s just printing before you do it. assign the var on one line then add this, **then** print it.

Comment: View my demo link.. I have it working correctly but what I'm saying is it still pulls the other links it doesn't just skip over the entire process.

Answer (score 2):

First

```
print $image = $image->content;
```

looks superflous.
It both sets $image = $image->content and prints it.

But instead of grabbing and printing each line one after another, grab the title, then decide if you want to fetch the other lines and print the record.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://beatshype.com/mp3download/');
foreach($html->find('.entry-title a') as $element) 
{
    $url = ''.$element->href;
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);
    $title = $html2->find('.single-title',0);

    if (strpos($title->plaintext,"MIXTAPE")===FALSE) { 
       $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
       $date = $html2->find('.single-content a',2);

       print '<br><br>';
       echo $url;
       print '<br>';
       print $image->content;
       print '<br>';
       print $title->plaintext;
       print '<br>';
       print $date->href;
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate you man, not sure why they was being dicks I was confused.